# How can I do a lazy regex matchAll with JavaSCript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect `job` and `jobs` in a piece of text. So `The jobs report came out and it was a great job!` should match `job` twice and `jobs` once.

If I do:

```
const res = str.matchAll(/job|jobs/gi)
```

Then it matches `jobs` once and `job` once. How can I modify it to do what I want?

**UPDATE**
Ultimately, I have a lot more like `/job|jobs|get\sa\sjob/`

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?  Do you want an array with `[job, jobs, job]`?  Something else?

Comment: Ideally, the array would be perfect

Comment: Seems like the simplest thing to do is add the `jobs` count to the `job` count after the matching is finished.

Comment: `str.match(/jobs?/gi).flatMap(m => m.endsWith('s') ? [m, m.slice(0, -1)] : m)` ?

Comment: ... how about ... `[...str.match(/jobs/gi), ...str.match(/job/gi)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most naive approach for achieving the OP's result was to just concat each match(ing) array of two separate regular expressions (here, the singular and the plural variant of `'job'`) ...

```js
const text = 'The jobs report came out and it was a great JOB!';

console.log(
  text.match(/jobs/gi).concat(text.match(/job/gi))
);
console.log(
  [...text.match(/jobs/gi), ...text.match(/job/gi)]
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

If one also wants to take into account word boundaries, as done by other answers, one has to change e.g. the second example of the above first approach to ...

```js
const text = 'The jobs report came out and it was a great NUTJOB of a JOB!';

// does not take word boundaries into account ...
console.log(
  [...text.match(/jobs/gi), ...text.match(/job/gi)]
);

// ... changed in order to support word boundaries.
console.log([
  ...text.match(/\bjobs\b/gi),
  ...[...text.matchAll(/\b(job)s?\b/gi)].map(([match, $1]) => $1)
]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a JavaScript person, and I couldn't get `matchAll` to work in a snippet here, nor in any other demo site.  So, I used an old-fashioned regex iterator.

For one solution, we can try matching on the following regex pattern:

```
\bjob(?=s|\b)|(?<=\bjob)s\b
```

This will match `job`, when it appears either as a standalone word, or when it appears as a substring of `jobs`.  The above alternation *also* matches the letter `s` when preceded by `job`.  Then, as we iterate, we replace the `s` match with `jobs`, to get the final result.

```js
var input = "The jobs report came out and it was a great job!";
var matches = [];
var counter = 0;
var re = /\bjob(?=s|\b)|(?<=\bjob)s\b/g;
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        matches[counter++] = m[0] === "job" ? "job" : "jobs";
    }
} while (m);

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also match either job or jobs by making the s optional.

Then afterwards loop the array, and if the string equals jobs, then add another job.

```js
let str = "The jobs report came out and it was a great job!";
const res = str.match(/\bjobs?\b/gi);
res.forEach(s => {
  if (s.toLowerCase() === "jobs") {
    res.push("job");
  }
});
console.log(res);
```